# Проблемы с загрузкой приложения

Tags: hibernate, java

Доброго времени суток.
Есть приложение так скажем "общий интерфейс" на котором есть определенные поля при нажатии на некоторое поле должно открываться java приложение написано отдельно. Таких приложений сейчас около 4, но одно не хочет запускаться пока не закроешь "интерфейс"(главную программу из которой идет вызов этого приложения). Неработающее приложение работает с БД и все реализовано с помощью hibernate и AWT. Все приложения написаны по разному но только в 1 используется hibernate. А главное приложение написано c помощью Swing.
Как сделать так что бы приложение запускалось сразу, а не после закрытия главного приложения?

Вызов приложения:

```
APtype = "5";
            if (InfraType.equals(APtype)){ // если тип обьекта = 'офис'
                try {
                    Process process =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar D://AgroApps//Personnel.jar ");
                } catch (IOException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
            }
```

Comment: А где вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

При запуске JVM укажите путь к библиотекам, которые вы используете в своем приложении через classpath.

Comment: @a_gura Подключил библиотеки но все равно приложение не запускается сразу, а только после того как закроешь главное приложение. Само же приложение если запускать отдельно то работает все нормально.

Comment: @jackVorobey Вы поменяли формулировку вопроса и тем самым сделали ответ бесполезным. И по вашему комментарию: я не медиум и не могу читать ваш код не видя его.

Comment: @a_gura
Какой именно код? Код вызова приложения приведен выше.

Comment: @jackVorobey у вас проблема где-то за пределами этого кода. Либо беда в формулировке самого вопроса.